# Bring Bootstrap Dropdown to front

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, z-index

I have the following dom tree:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item2</li>
    <li>Item3 That Has a List</li>
    <ul>
         <li class="sidebar-search">
              <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Αναζήτηση...">
                   <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a id="toolsDrop" href="" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" style="padding: 6px 6px 6px 8px;">Filters&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 0; top: 34px; left: -20px;">
                                    <li>Filter1</li>
                                    <li>Filter2</li>
                                    <li>Filter3</li>
                                    <li>Filter4</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                   </span>
              </div>
         </li>
         <li>
              <ul class="nav nav-second-level sidebar-device-list">Another list that gets filtered by the dropdown and thus, changes size
              </ul>
         </li>
    </ul>
    <li>Item4</li>
    <li>Item5</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see in these pictures:

[image: Dropdown Example] [image: Dropdown not in foreground]

, because the `<div class="dropdown">` is under a div inside a list, other list items, will be rendered above the dropdown menu, if the list element that has the dropdown button is too small. I have tried setting the z-index of the dropdown menu to 99999 but it doesn't work, because of how z-indexes work (given that the elements have different parents, they are in a different stacking order/scope [as shown in this article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)).

Is there any way, other than setting the positioning of the dropdown menu to `fixed`, to show it above the rest of the list? (I don't want it to be above everything in the page, just above the rest of the parent ul's elements.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Please share the css part too or working demo where we can see the issue in live. Thanx

Comment: No, but I'll try to make one asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FINALLY I remembered the cause:

the parent element has  `overflow-y: hidden`

Set that to initial/visible and the dropdown will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index` property with the higher values for the dropdown and lesser z-index for the other div which needs to go down.

Answer (score 0):

Try with giving `z-index:999` for `nav` class. It's worked for me.